Langchain downloading GPT4All model in terminal, even though i already have downloaded it before
The File Structure is :-
gpt4all/ 
    data/
       chagatai.txt
    models/
       mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf
    venv
    chatbot.py

The code in chatbot.py :-
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.embeddings import GPT4AllEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
# from langchain import RunnableSequence

model_path1 = "./models/mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf"
callback_manager = CallbackManager([])
llm = GPT4All(model=model_path1, callback_manager=callback_manager, verbose=True)

template = """
You are an AI assistant.
Given the following questions. Explain like the answer is for a 5 year old.

Question : {question}

Answer :
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['question'])

llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt = prompt, llm = llm)

loader = DirectoryLoader("data/", glob = "**/*.txt")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size = 1000, chunk_overlap = 0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# Create a vector store and add text chunks
embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings(model_name="mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf", model_path = model_path1)
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

# Create a retriever from vector store
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

# Load the question-answering chain with the retriever

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
llm=llm,
chain_type="stuff",
retriever=retriever,
return_source_documents=True,
)

# Ask a question
query = "What is your knowledge base?"
result = qa.invoke(input=query)
print(result)

Whenever I run this in my terminal using python chatbot.py
it starts downloading the model, even though I have already downloaded, saved and referenced it's path and name in my program.
For this chatbot.py code :-
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

model_path1 = "./models/mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf"
callback_manager = CallbackManager([])
llm = GPT4All(model=model_path1, callback_manager=callback_manager, verbose=True)

template = """
You are an AI assistant.
Given the following questions. Explain like the answer is for a 5 year old.

Question : {question}

Answer :
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['question'])

llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt = prompt, llm = llm)

while True :
query = input("Enter your question :- ")
result = llm_chain.invoke(input=query)
print(result['text'])

It doesn't download the model from terminal, and the code works properly. This makes me believe that the problem might be in one of the classes from additional libraries that I am using in the previous code snippet which has some setting to download the model on default. But I am not able to pinpoint it exactly.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you could add print() between your commands to see what it will print before it start downloading. OR you may start removing lines from your code until it will run without downloading - this way you will see which line makes problem.

The error is likely coming from this line:
embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings(model_name="mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf", model_path = model_path1)

GPT4AllEmbeddings requires you to explicitly set downloading as False. Here's how you can do that:
gpt4all_kwargs = {'allow_download': False}
embeddings = GPT4AllEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_path1,
    gpt4all_kwargs=gpt4all_kwargs
)

You can read more in the LangChain documentation, though the documentation is fairly sparse.
